# Преобразовать объект в массив объектов

Tags: javascript, алгоритм

Надо написать функцию, которая смогла бы "расплющить объект". Аргументы: **(data, name, fields)**.
Входные данные:

```
data = {
  foo: {qty: 1, price: 23},
  bar: {qty: 7, price: 182}
 };
name="zoo";
fields=["Кол-во","Цена"];
```

Возвращенный массив:

```
[
   {zoo: "foo", Кол-во: 1,  Цена:23},
   {zoo: "bar", Кол-во: 7,  Цена:182}
]
```

Заметьте, zoo равен названиям ключей из data

Comment: И что вы имеете в виду под расплющить?

Comment: @Zhenyria есть похожая функция flat, но для массивов. То есть надо раскрыть вложенные объекты. В данном случае все объекты построены по одинаковому шаблону: {a:{b:1, c:2}}

Comment: За что столько минусов?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const input = {
  foo: {qty: 1, price: 23},
  bar: {qty: 7, price: 182}
 };
const name="zoo";
const fields=["Кол-во","Цена"];

const output = Object.entries(input).map(
  ([val,props])=>({ [name]:val, ...
    Object.fromEntries(Object.values(props)
                       .map((prop,idx)=>[fields[idx],prop]))}));
                       
console.log(output);
```